How to resolve elastic-apm-node APM Server transport error (ENOTFOUND) error
I've been trying to solve an issue when implementing Elastic APM in a microservice. The APM container (apm-server) is running in Docker. I have a NodeJs microservice (test-service), also deployed in Docker, set up to use elastic-apm-node.
apm.start() initializes successfully but quickly generates getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND error.
What am I doing wrong?
The error:
 2024-07-18 15:13:20 {"log.level":"error","@timestamp":"2024-07-18T19:13:20.963Z","log.logger":"elastic-apm-node","ecs.version":"8.10.0","message":"APM Server transport error (ENOTFOUND): getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND apm-server"}
The agent code:
const apm = require('elastic-apm-node').start({
  serviceName: 'test-service',
  serverUrl: "http://apm-server:8200",
  secretToken: process.env.ELASTIC_APM_SECRET_TOKEN
});

const app = require('express')()

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Hello World!')
})

app.listen(5001)

docker-compose.yml
  elasticsearch:
   ...
  kibana:
   ...
  apm-server:
    image: docker.elastic.co/apm/apm-server:8.14.2
    container_name: apm-server
    restart: always
    command: >
      apm-server -e
        -E apm-server.rum.enabled=true
        -E setup.kibana.host=kibana:5601
        -E setup.template.settings.index.number_of_replicas=0
        -E apm-server.kibana.enabled=true
        -E apm-server.kibana.host=kibana:5601
        -E apm-server.kibana.username:kibana_system
        -E apm-server.kibana.password:xxxxxx
        -E apm-server.kibana.protocol=http
        -E apm-server.secret_token=
        -E strict.perms=false
        -E apm-server.auth.anonymous.enabled=true
    ports:
      - "8200:8200"
    volumes:
      - ./apm-server.yml:/usr/share/apm-server/apm-server.yml:ro
    networks:
      - elastic
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch

  test-service:
    build:
      context: ../test-service

    container_name: test-service

     environment:
      - RABBITMQ_URL=amqp://rabbitmq
      - ELASTICSEARCH_NODE=http://elasticsearch:9200
      - ELASTIC_APM_SERVER_URL=http://apm-server:8200
      - ELASTIC_APM_SECRET_TOKEN=secrettoken
      - PORT=5001

    ports:
      - "5001:5001"

    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch
      - rabbitmq
      - apm-server

I initially thought there was something related to using import instead of require to load the agent but the error persists whether I'm using ESM of CommonJS.
Docker commands:
**% docker compose up -d elasticsearch kibana rabbitmq apm-server**

**% docker compose up -d --build  test-service**

=\> \[test-service internal\] load build definition from Dockerfile              0.0s

 =\> =\> transferring dockerfile: 156B                                           0.0s

 =\> \[test-service internal\] load metadata for docker.io/library/node:20-alpin  0.3s

 =\> \[test-service internal\] load .dockerignore                                 0.0s

 =\> =\> transferring context: 2B                                                0.0s

 =\> \[test-service 1/5\] FROM docker.io/library/node:20-alpine@sha256:34b7aa411  0.0s

 =\> \[test-service internal\] load build context                                 0.1s

 =\> =\> transferring context: 620.21kB                                          0.1s

 =\> CACHED \[test-service 2/5\] WORKDIR /app                                     0.0s

 =\> CACHED \[test-service 3/5\] COPY package\*.json ./                            0.0s

 =\> CACHED \[test-service 4/5\] RUN npm install                                  0.0s

 =\> CACHED \[test-service 5/5\] COPY . .                                         0.0s

 =\> \[test-service\] exporting to image                                          0.0s

 =\> =\> exporting layers                                                        0.0s

 =\> =\> writing image sha256:605fb0a530197c6f8c86289b50c54bf063d0e4010d401d9bd  0.0s

 =\> =\> naming to docker.io/library/volumes-test-service                        0.0s

\[+\] Running 4/4

 ✔ Container rabbitmq       Running                                            0.0s 

 ✔ Container elasticsearch  Running                                            0.0s 

 ✔ Container apm-server     Running                                            0.0s 

 ✔ Container test-service   Started    


The two services aren't on the same networks: as you've shown it.  The easiest fix here is to delete all the networks: blocks in the entire file; Compose will create a network named default and attach the containers to it automatically.

Yup, that fixed it. Many thanks, David.
